# Regex to replace everything except trailing digits

Tags: java, regex, string, digits, replaceall

This should be pretty straight-forward, but I'm unable to find the answer nor come up with it. I have a String which always has one or more trailing digits, and potentially other digits elsewhere. I want to remove everything from the string except for all trailing digits.

Some example test cases:

```
"1 test50"               ->  "50"
"anothertest10"          ->  "10"
"can contain spaces123"  ->  "123"
"ok1"                    ->  "1"
```

I tried the most obvious thing: `str.replaceAll(".*(\\d)+$","$1")`, but unfortunately the `.*` is matched first, so for the test cases above it will result in `0,0,3,1` instead of `50,10,123,1`.

I have the feeling I need to use a look-behind or something, although I've barely used them in the past and I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem.

Comment: `(.*?)(\d+)$` [Link](https://regex101.com/r/2pkcev/1)

Comment: Basically, you may match the digits at the end of the string with the `[0-9]+$` pattern. Why do you want to use `replaceAll`? Edit: you might as well use `str.replaceFirst("(?s)(?:.*\\D)?(\\d+)$","$1")` to get to the end of string quicker and support line breaks in the string. But doesn't it look cumbersome?

Comment: @Gurman Thank you!`str.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+)$","$1")` worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the regex

```
\d+$
```

which would match all trailing digits, see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/MRIV1M/1)

Comment: I know that.. but how do I remove everything else with `replaceAll`.. (Have you've read the question description instead of just the title?..)

Comment: Why do you want to use replace all though ?

Comment: I personally think it's easier to read and shorter than a Pattern.compile with matcher iteration. Preference I guess.. Still thanks for answering, but I was already aware of what `\\d+$` does..